# Getting Internal Error when calling Firebase Cloud Function Directly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting the following Error when trying to call my Firebase Cloud Function directly:

```
Error: internal
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (error.ts:65)
    at _errorForResponse (error.ts:175)
    at Service.<anonymous> (service.ts:276)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:102)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:73)
```

I've noticed that users have seen similar issues in the past where the Firebase version 7.22.0 was causing it, and it was resolved in 7.22.1 but I'm on 8.3.0, so that shouldn't be a problem.

My cloud function is never being triggered, I don't see any errors in the Firebase Functions log.

Here is my client-side function:

```
async function testCallFunction() {
        const callTest = functions.httpsCallable('callTest');
        return await callTest({ companyId: coRef })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

And here is my Cloud Function:

```
exports.callTest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log('Call Test Fired')
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.auth.uid).get()
    .then((doc) => { return doc.data()})
    .catch(err => {throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err.message)})
})
```

But it's never reaching the cloud function I get the internal error only and no logs in the cloud function logs.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I have made sure I'm using the latest firebase JS SDK (8.3.0) and I've tried to stick as close to the doc as I can. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: there must be something wrong with your client side code otherwise cloud function should be called and show some logs.

Comment: yeah it looks like you need to downgrade your firebase version. try 7.22.1

Comment: What happens if you don't mix async/await and then (not recommended) and do as follows: `const result = await callTest({ companyId: coRef }); console.log(result);`? Also, is your user authenticated when he/she calls the function? In other words, is `context.auth.uid`having the expected value, in yoru Cloud Function?

Comment: Thanks @JeetChhatrala I'll try downgrading to that specific version, however I upgraded to 8.3.0 when I first encountered this issue, but I'll try this version, thanks.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes my user is authenticated, I've also tried doing it that way with the result =, but I also get the same error. And remember it's never getting to the actual cloud function anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing the exact same symptoms while using [AngularFireFunctions](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md) httpsCallable method. Recently updated firebase sdk to 8.3.1 from 8.2.4 and I suspect this introduced the https callable internal error. Downgrading to 8.2.4 resolves the issue:

npm install firebase@8.2.4 --save